# What does "HTTP request failed" mean in an rspec/capybara/poltergeist/phantomjs spec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

Even when all tests are passing, I see many many instances of this message amid the successful test output:

```
...
in the single-post view
    behaves like editing a comment
HTTP request failed.
HTTP request failed.
HTTP request failed.
...
```

What is causing it?

Comment: I don't know, but it's not normal. Have you looked at `page.driver.network_traffic`?

Comment: thanks, doing so shows a bunch of requests to third-party resources like analytics. i guess i should be catching those with webmock or something.

Comment: Can't do it with webmock since it's inside phantomjs. See the answer I just turned my comment into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is that requests made by for example third-party analytics scripts on your page are failing.

You can see their activity by inspecting the output of poltergeist's `page.driver.network_traffic` at the end of a test.

If you think this is the problem, you could take those scripts out of the picture by

- including them in the page only if you're not running tests, or
- using poltergeist's `page.execute_script` to replace appropriate functions in those third-party scripts with no-op functions. (That takes more work but leaves the page contents more production-like, which might catch a few more possible errors.)

Comment: hmm, seems like there should be a more reliable way to capture all outside traffic

Comment: That would be nice. I don't know of one.

Comment: [Puffing Billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy) intends to solve the problem of requests to third-party sites in tests. However, I haven't used it, and my colleague evaluated it and found it lacking somehow.